# PHP rtrim function trim extra character? Why?

Tags: php, character-trimming

How does `rtrim` work? I have a string "4dbb3dca&". I am not sure how my string is formmated.
I want to call `rtrim('4dbb3dca&', '&amp;')`

**--edit:`&` might be  `$amp;` special character issue**

But after my string is `4dbb3dc`.

I expect it to be `4dbb3dca`.

Is there any workaround? I ried to use `&`, but then rtrim does nothing and initial string is returned. Is it possible to use `rtrim` in my situation? Does it depend on php version?

--- edit ---

after some research I realized that I want:
I want remove `&` using `&amp;` in `rtrim()` function. Is this possible?

Comment: Just `&` works fine. What exactly did you try?

Comment: Have you read the manual already? http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: The second argument to rtrim is a character mask. Do you need to specifically remove `&amp;`, or just any of those characters?

Comment: I want remove ```&``` using ```&amp;``` in ```rtrim()```.

Answer (score 5):

**Q1**. Is it possible to use rtrim in my situation?
**Yes**, it is possible to use `rtrim()` in your situation.

**Q2**. Does it depend on php version?
**No**

You just need to use `echo rtrim('4dbb3dca&', '&');` not the `&amp;` because  2nd parameter of [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) works like below-

> You can also specify the **characters** you want to strip, by means of
>   the character_mask parameter. Simply list all **characters** that you
>   want to be stripped

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/anFIR

If you use this below example, then you'll get the same result because it'll try to remove all the given character(s) from the right side of your given string. For Ex-

```
echo rtrim('4dbb3dca&;pm', '&amp;');` // will also return 4dbb3dc
```

Answer (score 1):

The second string you specify in `rtim()` contains all the extra characters you want to trim. So the chars getting trimmed are `"&"` and  `"a"` (both are indeed included in the second parameter of your `rtrim()` function call, `"&amp"`).

To get the result that you want, you should invoke `rtrim()` this way:

```
rtrim('4dbb3dca&', '&')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to remove an ampersand from the end of the string, potentially in encoded form. `rtrim` doesn't give you enough control to do that, as you've seen, but you can do it with `preg_replace`.

```
echo preg_replace('/&(amp;)?$/', '', $string);
```

The pattern will match an ampersand at the end of the string, optionally followed by amp;.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `rtrim` works remove the last characters at the second argument.

the PHP has split the string to characters and make a check if you have the characters at last of the string.

if you have two characters from the list of characters the `rtrim` will remove both

For example :

`;&apm` it will be the same result like `&amp;`

if you want to remove the only ampersand symbol at the end of the string
use this code: `rtrim('4dbb3dca&','&');`

for understand more you can read about it at php.net 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php